# Error #1009 - I can't find why it says "null object reference"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent

I have problems with this error on my .fla. Could you help me, please ?
I debug my file and find where is the problem but cannot resolve it. It says :

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at
>   lacdeder_v3_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[lacdeder_v3_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:49]

My code is :

```
stop ();

btn_chap1_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_chap1_11);
btn_chap1_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_chap1_22);
btn_chap1_3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_chap1_33);
btn_chap2_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_chap2_11);
btn_chap2_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_chap2_22);
btn_chap2_3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_chap2_33);
btn_chap3_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_chap3_11);
btn_chap3_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_chap3_22);
btn_chap3_3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_chap3_33);

function btn_chap1_11(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("chap1_1");
}

function btn_chap1_22(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("chap1_2");
}

function btn_chap1_33(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndPlay("chap1_3");
}

function btn_chap2_11(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("chap2_1_1");
}

function btn_chap2_22(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("chap2_2_1");
}

function btn_chap2_33(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndPlay("chap2_3");
}

function btn_chap3_11(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("chap3_1");
}

function btn_chap3_22(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("chap3_2");
}

function btn_chap3_33(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("chap3_3");
}

date1910.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go1910);
date1938.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go1938);
date1955.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go1955);
date1969.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go1969);
date1974.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go1974);

function go1910(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("chap2_1_1");
}

function go1938(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("chap2_1_2");
}

function go1955(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("chap2_1_3");
}

function go1969(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("chap2_1_4");
}

function go1974(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("chap2_1_5");
}

btn_village1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, allervillage1);
btn_village2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, allervillage2);
btn_village3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, allervillage3);
btn_village4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, allervillage4);

function allervillage1(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("village1")
}

function allervillage2(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("village2")
}

function allervillage3(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("village3")
}

function allervillage4(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop("village4")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`date1910` is null, you need to define it either somewhere in your code or on the stage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "date1910" is the instance of my button. Do I have to defined it also on the stage ? like an instance of a frame ?

Comment: @Made I don't understand what you mean. The button's clip must be on the stage and you must give it an instance name.

Comment: That's what I did. My button btn_date1910 is on my stage and I gave it "date1910" for instance name. I verified a million times ! That's why I don't understand why it says "null object reference" ...

Comment: @Made Then I don't think there's enough information for me to really help you. All I can tell you is that reference to that object is null.

Comment: Can I send you a Dropbox link to my .fla in MP ?

Comment: @Made What's MP? Also, it wouldn't be very smart to send your entire source to someone you don't know, and I don't use SO to look through peoples' projects and find bugs. You just need to be more specific.